# cocoaHTTPserver multipart/form-data timing out?

Tags: ios, cocoahttpserver

I'm trying to setup a file server inside of my iOS application. I have cocoaHTTPserver setup to do the leg work.  It didn't support POST for large-file uploads out of the box so I modifying it to get it working by piping the content body out to a file stream.  However, for some strange reason I can never seem to get past around 44MB during an upload.  The stream is set for a 30 second timeout and after anywhere from 10-44MB the stream just stop receiving data?  The headers look fine coming in (example from Safari but same problem on Chrome):

```
Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
"Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate";
"Accept-Language" = "en-us";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 1256657607;
"Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7n0hAe769NCJsl2R";
Host = "192.168.1.102:8088";
Origin = "http://192.168.1.102:8088";
Referer = "http://192.168.1.102:8088/";
"User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML,   like Gecko) Version/5.1 Safari/534.45";
```

Any help would be much appreciated.